# Bulk upload large images to cloudinary

Tags: cloudinary

Is there a way to bulk upload images to my cloudinary account?

I am looking to import 100 images of 3MB each at a time.

Thank you.

Comment: related to - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40206693/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cloudinary's upload API to upload images one by one. [Here is a sample upload code in Python](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary#upload).
If your images are already in a public location, you can specify the remote HTTP URL as the `file` parameter instead of sending the actual image's data. This allows much faster uploading. If your images are in an Amazon S3 bucket, images can be fetched by Cloudinary directly from S3 for reaching even higher upload performance.

You can also run your upload code using multiple processes in parallel for quickly uploading multiple files simultaneously. In our Ruby on Rails client library we included [a migration tool](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#migration).

Currently there is no dedicated API method of Cloudinary for performing bulk upload of images.

Comment: Hi, this answer is 5 years old. Do you guys still don't have any API means to parallelly upload multiple images to Cloudinary?

Comment: Hi. :) 
I asked [here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/issues/197) almost the same now in 2020. Based on the doc, it's possible from Java, but I don't think so. Is there anybody who knows the solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use the remote API - and Just pass the url reference to the account and Cloudinary will connect to the image and download it into your account.

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#remote_upload