# create FormData instance for each file in <input type=file multiple>

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I'm trying to use input file with `multiple` attribute and to have the formData split so I would have a formData isnatce for each file in the multiple file element.

#### HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple></label>
```

#### JS

```
new FormData(formElement) // <--- Need to have this for each file selected
```

I need this because I'm using Cloudinary API and they only accept one file at a time, so I need to send multiple Ajax requests and for each, I need `formData` instance for each of the files selected, but the problem is, `FormData` accepts as an argument the how `form` element, and I cannot separate the files.

### [DEMO PAGE](http://jsbin.com/jomokic/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Are you trying to call `$.ajax()` for each file selected? Note, second parameter to `FormData.prototype.append()` should be data to be set, third parameter is file name, if any

Comment: It seems Cloudinary API REST is expecting `FormData` to be instantiated only with the `form` which is the DOM form element...

Comment: See https://github.com/cloudinary/pkg-cloudinary-core#installation ,  http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_image_uploads_from_the_browser_to_the_cloud_with_jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.when()`, `$.map()` to append each `File` of `<input type="file">` `FileList` to new `FormData` instance, then call `$.ajax()` for each `FormData()` instance.

Note, substituted `.on()` for `onsubmit` event attribute. Without `required` attribute or a default `.value` set `name="cloud_name"` and `name="upload_preset"` `<input type="text">` elements `.value` could be an empty string when `form` `submit` event occurs.

```
$(function() {
  var form = $("form");
  form.on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloudName = $('input[name="cloud_name"]').val(),
      presetName = $('input[name="upload_preset"]').val(),
      URL = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudName + "/image/upload",
      input = form.find("[name=file]");

    $.when.apply($, $.map(input[0].files, function(file, index) {
      var data = new FormData(form[0]);
      data.append("upload_preset", file, file.name);
      return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: URL,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
      });
    }))
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
  })
})
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/7l0obsusqXVlommdd49L?p=preview

Comment: yes obviously.. but this is not what I need, as I said, to create multiple instances of `FormData`, and you are creating only one. I cannot use this since Cloudinary doesn't support this. also, out of curiosity, I have tested it, and it does not work. do you have experience with Cloudinary unsigned uploads?

Comment: I have a [response from their support](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/37289) confirming this

Comment: Have not tried Cloudinary. Will update Answer with an approach which posts a request for each file selected. The link redirects to a login page.

Comment: `TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.`

Comment: @vsync Ah, passed jQuery object. Should be `new FormData(form[0])` to get `DOM` element http://plnkr.co/edit/7l0obsusqXVlommdd49L?p=preview

Comment: it sends the last selected file 3 times. also had to change it to `data.append("upload_preset", presetName);` as it was before, for it to work. `upload_present` must be a unique string I've created in my account

Comment: Their API is horrible.. anway, I'm using un-signed uploaded so I must specify something called `upload_present`.. and append it to the `FormData`

Comment: _"it sends the last selected file 3 times."_ Not certain how this could occur? Can adjust to perform each `$.ajax()` call in sequential order if that is necessasry

Comment: @vsync An approach using `.queue()` http://plnkr.co/edit/7l0obsusqXVlommdd49L?p=preview

Comment: [Araz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206693/create-formdata-instance-for-each-file-in-input-type-file-multiple#answer-40207634) gave me the actual clue I wanted and I made it work, but thank you SO MUCH for helping!!!!

Comment: @vsync That is the same pattern used at version 2 of plnkr; that is, using `$.map()`, though you did append two keys, values at your updated jsbin. Browsed the documentation, though could not find a clear demonstration using `FormData()`. What exactly does Cloudinary do?

Comment: it's an images hosting service that lets you do tons of image manipulations simply by modifying the url. it's like imageMagic / GD2 but as SaaS product. I didn't know I could instantiate formData without any parameters and then fill it up with the files manually, for some reason i was stuck with the thought that the form had to be passed as a parameter.. I blame myself for not thinking out-of-the-box no this one.

Comment: it is resolved and working.the problem is, I cannot chose any of the answers, since yours has this whole async thing with the `$.when..` which is irrelevant, and the other answer was only a big clue but it did not explain how to actually do it, since I had pieced it together

Answer (score 2):

Each time you make a formData object you can append to it data like this:

```
data.append("file", document.getElementById(file).files[0]);
```

but instead of 0 in for loop you can put loop index and send data to ajax.

and you should initialize data by following :

```
 var data = new FormData();
```

Comment: yes but how do I iterate `form.file.files` ? it's not a "real" array, loops and Array methods don't apply to it

Comment: i think if you use getElementById you can access like array see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400191/get-the-files-chosen-using-the-input-type-file-multiple-and-store-them-in-an-a