# How to upload multiples images from ftp media server to cludinary?

Tags: cloudinary

I'm looking for a solution to load multiples images from ftp media server to cloudinary. I searched on the net and I found these links:

1. [How can I bulk upload my images?](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-)
2. [Bulk upload large images to cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003807/bulk-upload-large-images-to-cloudinary)
3. [Data upload options](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#data_upload_options):

> If your images are already publicly available online, you can specify their remote HTTP or HTTPS URLs instead of uploading the actual data. In this case, Cloudinary will fetch the image from its remote URL for you. This option allows for a much faster migration of your existing images

There is no information about uploading images from an ftp media server or something like that. All the available solutions are using a script and then upload images one by one.In my case I have on my server many folders of images and in each folder there are many sub-folders and I have about 10000 images.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload to Cloudinary using an FTP source like this (in PHP):

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload('ftp://username:password@ftp.mydomain.com/my_image.jpg');
```

Comment: this instruction allows a single file upload.

Comment: Indeed, Cloudinary doesn't support bulk upload operations via the API. You can use multi-threads for concurrent upload requests (limited to up to approximately 50 concurrent requests).